# Conditional probability in component network

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am a little stuck on this problem involving the below reliability network:

[image: Reliability Network]

The probability that any given component works is independent with probability $p$, and fails with probability $q=1-p$. I am trying to find the probability that components $1$ and $5$ work given that the system works.

Starting with the probability the system works I get the probability that components $1$ and $2$ work is $p^2$, the probability that components $4$ and $5$ work is $1-q^2$. Therefore the probability that components $3$, $4$, and $5$ work is $p(1-q^2)$, hence:

$$P(\textrm{System Works})=1-(1-p^2)(1-p(1-q^2))$$

This can be simplified but I do not think it is too important. I then try to find the probability that $1$, $5$, and the system works. I am struggling on this part, it seems like there are many combinations where this condition is satisfied, so I was wondering if there is a better way to consider all the events which the system works as well as components $1$ and $5$?

Just to clarify what I mean by a reliability network. The probability that the system works is a path getting from the right to left side (or vice versa) passing through components that work with probability $p$. You cannot pass through a component if it fails (probability $1-p$ defined to be $q$).

Comment: Could you please indicate what is the role of the structure of the network. If the components have independent probability to work $p$ and $q$ to fail, isn't the probability you are looking for $1-q^5$ actually?

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully clarify your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Let } && S = \mbox{System works} \\
&& W = \mbox{1 and 5 both work.}
\end{eqnarray*}

With the obvious notation, and using distributivity rules:
\begin{eqnarray*}
S &=& (3 \cap (4 \cup 5)) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2) \\
&=& (3 \cap 4) \;\cup\; (3 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2). \\
W &=& 1 \cap 5. \\
\therefore S \cap W &=& \left[(3 \cap 4) \;\cup\; (3 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2)\right] \;\cap\; (1 \cap 5) \\
&=& (1 \cap 3 \cap 4 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 3 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2 \cap 5) \\
&=& (1 \cap 3 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2 \cap 5). \\
\therefore P(S \cap W) &=& P(1 \cap 3 \cap 5) + P(1 \cap 2 \cap 5) - P(1 \cap 2 \cap 3 \cap 5) \quad\mbox{by inclusion-exclusion} \\
&=& 2p^3 - p^4.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Did OP already calculated $P(S)$.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: @Did No problem :-)

Comment: Hi I don't see why $(1 \cap 3 \cap 4 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 3 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2 \cap 5)
= (1 \cap 3 \cap 5) \;\cup\; (1 \cap 2 \cap 5)$, does this not imply $(1 \cap 3 \cap 4 \cap 5)$ is 'zero'?

Comment: @Johnmgee $(1 \cap 3 \cap 4 \cap 5) \subseteq (1 \cap 3 \cap 5)$ so $(1 \cap 3 \cap 4 \cap 5) \cup (1 \cap 3 \cap 5) = 1 \cap 3 \cap 5$.

Comment: I see, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I would use chain rule for:

$P$(System works,**One** ok,**Five** ok)=$P$(System works|**One** ok,**Five** ok)$P$(**One** ok,**Five** ok)

Assuming **one** ok and **five** ok:

- **one** can be eliminated from the network (passes always through).
- similarly you can eliminate **five** - there is just a straight line
- finally, if you pass five all the time, you can eliminate **four**: you can use always the line where was **five**
- the remaining nodes are **two** and **three**, in the same arrangement as **four** and **five** in the original picture

Therefore we get:

$P$(System works|**One** ok,**Five** ok) = $1-q^2$

From the formulation and independence, we get

$P$(**One** ok,**Five** ok) =  $p^2$

Thus $P$(System works,**One** ok,**Five** ok) = $p^2(1-q^2)$

Comment: Ok that clears a few things up. I was confident you could eliminate 1, but I wasn't sure you could eliminate 4 like that.